# Can't get whole picture on the screen of a new monitor

Tags: video, monitor, radeon, graphics

I have a 24inch, VM2453mh-LED, Viewsonic monitor using a Radeon 6570HD video card. Both are new. Viewsonic says the optimum size is 1920x1080. At this size the picture is beautiful, but it overlaps the screen vertically and horizontally. I am using Ubuntu 11.10, the Gnome 3 version, not Unity. On the Overview screen, the vertical icons are nearly off screen. Only the right edge shows. I opened the monitor's control menus to see if I could adjust it, but both the H/V Position and Horizontal Size are grayed out.
I tried a 1600x1200 setting, and the picture was in bounds, but the quality was less, and it was stretched horizontally. The two monitor menu options were grayed out just like with the 1920x1080 setting.
Can someone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can adjust this by using the AMD Radeon Catalyst Control Center application. In looking for solutions to a different problem I read a fair amount about "overscan" and "underscan" and by adjusting the "scaling options" you may be able to resolve the issue at 1920x1080. See this link for some info that might be helpful: http://www.justin.my/2011/12/cannot-display-full-screen-using-ati-amd-radeon/